# Getting error 403:forbidden while creating a function app in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, storage

While creating a function app in azure i need code and associated files to be stored in the storage account but the network setting of the storage account should set to “Enabled from selected Vnets and IP's", I am getting error

> 403:forbidden while trying to upload the file to Azure fileshare while
> creating a function app via ARM Templates.

How to resolve this?

When i tried "Enabled from all networks" in storage account network setting i was able to deploy but i need to deploy from "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses".

Comment: hi @prabha Karan, can you please share the code then it will be helpful.

Comment: @SureshChikkam Since the code was developed by my organization, I cannot share it. Is there any other way I can help you by sharing the other details to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to deploy from "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses".

- I have created a storage account, Vnet and Enabled access by adding IP address to the storage account and I am able to achieve the above requirement successfully.

Below is the template that works for me.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the storage account."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountSku": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_ZRS",
        "Premium_LRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage account SKU."
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkResourceGroup": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Resource group containing the virtual network."
      }
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the virtual network."
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the subnet within the virtual network."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "networkRuleSet": {
      "defaultAction": "Deny",
      "virtualNetworkRules": [
        {
          "subnetId": "[resourceId(parameters('virtualNetworkResourceGroup'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), parameters('subnetName'))]",
          "action": "Allow"
        }
      ],
      "ipRules": [],
      "bypass": "AzureServices"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountSku')]"
      },
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "properties": {
        "networkAcls": {
          "defaultAction": "[variables('networkRuleSet').defaultAction]",
          "virtualNetworkRules": "[variables('networkRuleSet').virtualNetworkRules]",
          "ipRules": "[variables('networkRuleSet').ipRules]",
          "bypass": "[variables('networkRuleSet').bypass]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "storageAccountConnectionString": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')),'2019-06-01').keys[0].value, ';EndpointSuffix=', environment().suffixes.storageEndpoint)]"
    }
  }
}
```

Iam able to deploy the above template in my Environment.
[image]

**Result :**
[image]